# phpmyadmin and foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, phpmyadmin

I added a foreign key constraint to one of my fields.

On insert, the field is showing up as a drop down instead of a text box, as expected.

But the drop down has each value listed twice, once with a minus sign before the value and once with the minus sign after the value.

Like this:

```
- value1
- value2
- value3
value1 -
value2 -
value3 -
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Phpmyadmin by default shows foreign key value and a *custom description field* next to it (which is set in "Relation view" for the table) separated by hyphen.

See also the phpMyAdmin FAQ 6.21, "[In edit/insert mode, how can I see a list of possible values for a column, based on some foreign table?](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/faq.html#in-edit-insert-mode-how-can-i-see-a-list-of-possible-values-for-a-column-based-on-some-foreign-table)".

Comment: Thanks for the info and link.  I now understand why it exists but I am not seeing a  "display field" in the relation view that it is referring to.  It only allows me to pick the relation and on delete, on update.  Do you know why I don't see this display field?  I am using v5.3.5

Comment: @swisscheese You probably don't have pmadb set up (see http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net/pma/pmadb)

Comment: The above explains why it's number-dash-nothing. Why there is also another nothing-dash-number becomes indeed clear from the wiki: "You will see two lists of values, the first list containing the key and the display field, the second list containing the display field and the key. The reason for this is to be able to type the first letter of either the key or the display field."  Would be a smart of phpMyAdmin  if ( comment==='' ) skipThisDashAndDoubleStuff();

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, pmadb does have to be set up however I found that this is set automatically. What you need to do is:

1. In the original table go into the relations view and choose which column to display (for example the descriptive name of the row ie: company name)
2. In the table where you wish to create the foreign key choose the column to display - which is probably going to be an integer ie: (companyID).

When you then go to insert you will find that you can see the both the integer and the corresponding name - ie: 1 - Company name