# How do I display content for foreign keys in phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Whenever I try to insert a new record in my MySQL database using phpMyAdmin, if the column refers to a foreign key, i get a dropdown box with the valid IDs that i can use. The problem is when the database gets too big, the ID is meaningless for me. For example if the ID is the social security number of the employee, i don't know it, but i can probably remember the name. Is there a way to display the row contents next to the ID or at least one column that could be more meaningful to the user? I have seen that feature in phpPgAdmin.

I tried this in the config file:

```
$cfg['ForeignKeyDropdownOrder'] = array( 'content-id', 'id-content' );
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure, that if the tables grow that big, phpMyAdmin is the best tool for the job?

Comment: It's not that big, but big enough to need the feature :D

Comment: Phpmyadmins purpose isn't that what you looking for. Your admin panel should do this job.

Comment: If your on mac try using sequelpro.  phpmyadmin isn't a great tool.

Comment: Well, my question is still the same, is there a way to display the row contents in those selects? Doesn't matter if that's what i need or not, i just want to know if it's possible.

Comment: possible duplicate of [phpmyadmin and foreign keys](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480859/phpmyadmin-and-foreign-keys)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

phpMyAdmin has a function for this, but you must be using the InnoDB table type. You must also have [pmadb](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#linked-tables) configured.

1. Select the table that contains the foreign key (child).
2. Click the "Structure" tab.
3. Click "Relation view".
4. Under the foreign key constraints, click the "Choose column to display" drop down and make a choice.

The column value will now be shown next to the id. It will also be shown when hovering over the foreign key value after making a selection.

For anyone having trouble getting this setup, please see the [#relation-view](https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/relations.html#relation-view) documentation which tells you exactly how to configure it with screenshots.

Comment: Thanks! Also, you probably won`t see any difference until you reload phpmyadmin or recreate main table foreign keys (at least for me)

Comment: Thanks this still works fine in 2022, only I had to make the change at the parent table instead of the child table

Answer (score 10):

In addition to what @EternalHour says you also need to check the radio button under **view options**
[image]

that says **"Relational display column"** if you want the value to be displayed.

[image]

If not checked you will only see the Foreign Key value when you hover that specific id.

Comment: How do you get to that view options page?

Comment: I believe this is on the structure tab.

Comment: It's on the Browse tab and I don't see those options for storage engine InnoDB.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to keep using phpmyadmin for this, you can create a view with a join which shows you the name, id and other information in 1 table. Then you can just use the search function to search on a name.

Comment: It seems like the functionality is already in another section: if you create a foreign key constraint, then perform INSERT, it will show the foreign table's content. The textbox to insert has changed to a dropdown featuring names or other data referenced by the foreign key.

Why the developers didn't add this feature to the Browse tab is beyond me.